# How to store API endpoints in AsyncStorage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, websocket, react-hooks, asyncstorage

Can we store API ENDPOINTs in async storage and retrieve them back from it ?.
for example, can I use it like this?

```
const [socket, setSocket] = useState();

useEffect(()=>{
  const socket = io('url');
  setSocket(socket);
},[]);


const setSocket= async (value) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('key', value)
  } catch(e) {
   console.log(e);
  }

  console.log('Done.')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Async storage is nothing but a `key value store`, you can store the api end points like the way you did.